# break-after: avoid; equivalent in flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make some kind of dictionary with flex. My elements are added from top to bottom then left to right (the flex element `.dictionary` grows on the right instead of the bottom. My `.dic-entry` entries stay coherent/together because they are each wrapped in an `<article>` tag. However, between them, there are "letter titles" `.dic-letter-title` and they should stay together  with the next `.dic-entry`.

In a column layout I would do `break-after: avoid`, how could I achieve this effect with flex elements?

**IMPORTANT EDIT: To clarify, I'm able to circumvent the problem and make the result look exactly as I want. However I'm looking for a *semantically-correct* solution. Not one where I have to wrap two element together with a meaningless element for example.**

EDIT: As @Nisha suggested in the comment I could wrap `.dic-letter-title` and the first `.dic-entry` in a container, however I'd like to avoid doing that as it is not semantically correct. If I wanted to add a semantically-correct container, it would have to be around all the dic-entry sharing the same first letter, but then they would form a bloc and I don't want that either.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%
}

body, main, article {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}

main, .container {
  min-height: 0;
}

.dictionary {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.dic-letter-title {
  /* DEBUG: This isn't working */
  break-after: avoid;
  color: red;
}

.dic-entry, .dic-entry * {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}

.dic-entry * {
  margin: 0;
}

.dic-entry {
  width: 16ch;
  padding: 0 2.5em 1.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<article class="container">
  <section class="dictionary small-text">
    <h3 class="dic-letter-title">Aa</h3>
    <article class="dic-entry"><h4>Aliquam consequat</h4>
    <p>Aliquam consequat vestibulum magna nec consequat.</p></article>

    <article class="dic-entry"><h4>Aliquam fermentum</h4>
    <p>Aliquam fermentum quis arcu vitae maximus.</p></article>

    <h3 class="dic-letter-title">Ll</h3>
    <article class="dic-entry"><h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></article>

    <h3 class="dic-letter-title">Mm</h3>
    <article class="dic-entry"><h4>Mauris blandit</h4>
    <p>Mauris blandit, enim a aliquam convallis, felis turpis ultricies dolor, in blandit velit lorem at nulla.</p></article>

    <h3 class="dic-letter-title">Pp</h3>
    <article class="dic-entry"><h4>Pellentesque habitant</h4>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p></article>

    <article class="dic-entry"><h4>Phasellus</h4>
    <p>Phasellus in bibendum nisi.</p></article>

    <h3 class="dic-letter-title">Uu</h3>
    <article class="dic-entry"><h4>Quisque nec eros</h4>
    <p>Quisque nec eros quis orci venenatis porttitor vitae sed nunc.</p></article>

    <h3 class="dic-letter-title">Uu</h3>
    <article class="dic-entry"><h4>Sed vulputate</h4>
    <p>Sed vulputate id orci sed maximus.</p></article>
  </section>
</article>
```

EDIT: I tried @zangab's solution of using list which mases sense semantically. However, now the "letter-group" title is solidary with what comes next, however now it's the whole letter-group can't wrap because the li can't be broken.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%
}

body, main, article, .disc-entry {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}

main, .container {
  min-height: 0;
}

.dictionary {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.dictionary li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.dic-letter-title {
  /* DEBUG: This isn't working */
  break-after: avoid;
  color: red;
}

.dic-entry, .dic-entry * {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}

.dic-entry * {
  margin: 0;
}

.dic-entry {
  width: 16ch;
  padding: 0 2.5em 1.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<article class="container">
  <ul class="dictionary small-text">
    <li class="dic-letter">
      <h3 class="dic-letter-title">Aa</h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="dic-entry">
          <h4>Aliquam consequat</h4>
          <p>Aliquam consequat vestibulum magna nec consequat.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="dic-entry">
          <h4>Aliquam fermentum</h4>
          <p>Aliquam fermentum quis arcu vitae maximus.</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dic-letter">
      <h3 class="dic-letter-title">Ll</h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="dic-entry">
          <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dic-letter">
      <h3 class="dic-letter-title">Mm</h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="dic-entry">
          <h4>Mauris blandit</h4>
          <p>Mauris blandit, enim a aliquam convallis, felis turpis ultricies dolor, in blandit velit lorem at nulla.</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dic-letter">
      <h3 class="dic-letter-title">Pp</h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="dic-entry">
          <h4>Pellentesque habitant</h4>
          <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="dic-entry">
          <h4>Phasellus</h4>
          <p>Phasellus in bibendum nisi.</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dic-letter">
      <h3 class="dic-letter-title">Qq</h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="dic-entry">
          <h4>Quisque nec eros</h4>
          <p>Quisque nec eros quis orci venenatis porttitor vitae sed nunc.</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dic-letter">
      <h3 class="dic-letter-title">Uu</h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="dic-entry">
          <h4>Sed vulputate</h4>
          <p>Sed vulputate id orci sed maximus.</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

Comment: dic-letter-title wrap it in article also or use div to wrap both dic-letter-title and article so it will always combine together

Comment: You're technically right, but I don't want to do that as it is not semantically correct. If I wanted to add a container it would be around all the dic-entry sharing the same first letter, but then they would form a bloc and I don't want that either.

Comment: @GaetanL. you could wrap the elements in a list so that every title starts with a new `<li>` item, so it's semantically correct. it's sort of a listing anyway. questionable is the `article` though as it's just some "intro" thing and just wrapping a headline, but this would always need some text at least otherwise you can just use the headline tag.

Comment: @zangab what structure would you give it? I concur that it would semantically make sense, but I'm just switching articles with list would result in the same display problems (I'm gonna try now).

Answer (score 0):

have a look here:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%
}

body, main, article {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}

main, .container {
  min-height: 0;
}

.dictionary {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.dic-letter-title {
  color: red;
}

.dic-entry, .dic-entry * {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}

.dic-entry * {
  margin: 0;
}

.dic-entry {
  width: 16ch;
  padding: 0 2.5em 1.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<article class="container">
  <ul class="dictionary small-text">
    <li>
      <h3 class="dic-letter-title">Aa</h3>
      <article class="dic-entry">
        <h4>Aliquam consequat</h4>
        <p>Aliquam consequat vestibulum magna nec consequat.</p>
      </article>

      <article class="dic-entry">
        <h4>Aliquam fermentum</h4>
        <p>Aliquam fermentum quis arcu vitae maximus.</p>
      </article>
    </li>

    <li>
      <h3 class="dic-letter-title">Ll</h3>
        <article class="dic-entry">
          <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </article>
    </li>

    <li>
      <h3 class="dic-letter-title">Mm</h3>
      <article class="dic-entry">
        <h4>Mauris blandit</h4>
        <p>Mauris blandit, enim a aliquam convallis, felis turpis ultricies dolor, in blandit velit lorem at nulla.
        </p>
      </article>

    <li>
      <h3 class="dic-letter-title">Pp</h3>
      <article class="dic-entry"><h4>Pellentesque habitant</h4>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p></article>

    <article class="dic-entry"><h4>Phasellus</h4>
    <p>Phasellus in bibendum nisi.</p></article></li>

    <li>
    <h3 class="dic-letter-title">Uu</h3>
    <article class="dic-entry"><h4>Quisque nec eros</h4>
    <p>Quisque nec eros quis orci venenatis porttitor vitae sed nunc.</p></article></li>

    <li>
    <h3 class="dic-letter-title">Uu</h3>
    <article class="dic-entry"><h4>Sed vulputate</h4>
    <p>Sed vulputate id orci sed maximus.</p></article></li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

Comment: You have the same problem as my 2nd edit: the blocks of same-letter entries cannot break, you'll get col1: aa, col2: bbb instead of col1: aab, col2: bb.

Comment: it highly doubt this is achievable with CSS only. it depends on text-lengths / window widths, etc. the title would need to know if it's at the bottom or not. @GaetanL.

Comment: That's a shame, thank you very much for your time, I ended up modifying my structure and tags to make them more semantic following your comments :)